# NSlookup of static IP showing computer name from DHCP range

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, nslookup

I am part of a network with 60 or so maximum devices. Just a class C subnet where x.x.x.1-100 are statically addressed hardware. 101-150 are also statically assigned addresses for thinclients and 'kiosks'. 151+ is the DHCP range for office laptops.

I am trying to 'map' the computers remotely rather than checking each IP on the floor. I did a `broadcast ping` and `arp -a` in hopes to grab all connected devices and started to nslookup the list to match computer names with IP's.

THE PROBLEM: `nslookup x.x.x.114` returned a computer name that should be in the DHCP range(151+). When I checked that computer's address it showed x.x.x.161, where it should be. I have done a `/flushdns` and `/registerdns` with no change.  **Edit:** I have seen incorrect/conflicting nslookups on the network before where `nslookup 'address'` returns a name and `nslookup 'name'` returns a different address.  I know NS can be do weird things but this specific static vs dynamic was not something I expected to see.

TLDR: Why would nslookup x.x.x.114 show the name of a computer in a DHCP range when the named computer has always been assigned through DHCP to another range?

**Edit more info**: Not sure if this question will have an answer but here is another finding.  113 is returning a 'windows-phone' with nslookup and Advanced IP scanner.  114 is still showing the DHCP computer.  I found the computers with 113 and 114 and they have been at those addresses for at least 6 months.

Comment: If you use the other computer, the one that had the "incorrect" address, and look up the computer you originally used what is that computer's address?

Comment: I have seen this before, it seems that it doesn't matter where I do the lookup from, still trying to find the 114 computer...

Comment: You made no mention of having this problem in the past.

Comment: edited, I did not notice if the other time I've seen it, it was across the static and dhcp range.

Comment: Could this just be that we need to clear our server DNS record?  starting to get away from this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing stale PTR records in DNS is all.  There's something broken with the normal cleanup mechanisms in the DHCP server that would delete these entries after leases expired.  In general, PTR record lookup is not reliable for finding names of devices anyway.

It can also be the case that these are leftover from when (1) the DHCP dynamic range included those IP addresses and was subsequently reconfigured, (2) the MAC address was defined in a reservation with those old IPs, or (3) someone statically configured those IP address(es) on client(s) that were AD-domain joined.  (You didn't say if this was a Microsoft environment or not.)  If the IP address doesn't ping, you can almost certainly just delete the stale entries.  If the DHCP server configuration is good now, PTR records will be repopulated when the machine comes back at that IP anyway.

Comment: Cleared those to address in the DNS and it picked up the new ones, renamed the computers and it automatically took that change as well.  Other info, most of the network is AD but the 113/114 in question are non-AD Thin-clients locked down by the rules about their ip range.